# How do I send plaintext email?

Tags: 7, mimemail

I've been using a combination of `drupal_mail()` and Mimemail to send out HTML formatted email; it's working fine.  However, in some circumstances, I also need to be able to send out plaintext email, not an empty HTML template, but a completely raw, plaintext message.

I can't figure out how to disable Mimemail for these messages, while leaving Mimemail in place for the others.

How might I be able to do this?

Answer (score 3):

I've spent some time trying to achieve the same goal.
I didn't find a lot of documentation on MimeMail module, I inspected the code and found a solution :

```
  $message = drupal_mail('my_module', 'my_module_key', 'email@mail.com', $language,
    $params = array(
      'subject' => $subject,
      'plain' => TRUE,
      'plaintext' => $mailBody,
    ));
```

You just need to use `'plain' => TRUE` and put your mail content in `'plaintext' => $mailBody`

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, I think:

(1) For some module, create a mail template to handle the plaintext requests, the details of which depend on how you're putting together your messages.  For me, this works:

```
function mymodule_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
     switch ($key) {
          ...
          case 'plaintext':
               $message['subject'] = $params['message_header'];
               $message['body'] = $params['message_body'];
               break;
     }
}
```

(2) Use `mailsystem_set` to set up an entry in the `mail_system` variable that points to the combined module and the key -- `mymodule_plaintext` in this case -- and that specifies the mail system DefaultMailSystem:

```
  module_load_include('module', 'mailsystem');
  mailsystem_set(
    array(
      'vr_random_plaintext' => 'DefaultMailSystem',
    )
  );
```

(See `mimemail.module` for tips on doing this; since it only needs to be run once, they recommend doing it in a `hook_enable` handler.)

(3) You should then be able to send plaintext messages by calling `drupal_mail()` and specifying `mymodule` and `plaintext` as the module and mail_template for the message.

This is working for me, although I may have glossed over a thing or two.  If there are questions, post away...